# how to update record in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

am using stripe for users to subscribe. from there i collected the stripe date and save it in subscription mode. i created enum for my user model to assign different roles base on the stripe subscription id.
here is how my user model looks like

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:user, :gold, :platinum, :diamond ]
  has_one :subscription
  has_one :shipping
  extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :firstname, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

and bellow is my subscription controller

```
   def subscription_checkout
     user = current_user
     plan_id = params[:plan_id]
     plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(plan_id)
     # This should be created on signup.
     customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
         description: 'Customer for test@example.com',
         source: params[:stripeToken],
         email: 'test@example.com'
     )
     # Save this in your DB and associate with the user;s email
     stripe_subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(plan: plan.id)
     @sub = Subscription.create(plan: stripe_subscription.plan.name,
                                stripeid: stripe_subscription.id,
                                user_id: current_user.id,
                                customer: stripe_subscription.customer,
                                subscriptionenddate: stripe_subscription.current_period_end)
     if @sub.save
         current_user.role  plan.id
         current_user.save
         flash[:success] = 'sub created!'
         redirect_to root_url
     else
         render 'new'
     end
 end
```

when it reach to update the role i get

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

how can i update the role and what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried: `current_user.role = plan.id` ?

It looks like you are just calling the `role()` method on the `curent_user` object.

Comment: that works. now am getting `undefined method `diamond?' for #<User` even thou in my rails console returns `user.diamond?
=> true`

Comment: Where's your surrounding code? Did you hop into the console by placing a debugger before the error was thrown or did you just open IRB?